# Check if a click is made in an entire HTML page containing Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, click

I'm currently developing a Web application that uses HTML and JavaScript. I have a problem related to my comboboxes, and now, what I need is to check if a clicked is pressed in my entire page.

The thing is, when I use JavaScript to check if a click is made, it's not properly checking my JavaScript area.

```
    $("html").click(function () 
    {
        alert("Click");
    });
```

I have an area that can be retracted with a - (minus) button that I made, which means it's dynamic. When this area is visible, every time I click on it doesn't count as a click in my HTML page (as the .click doesn't seem to like dynamic stuff).

Do you have an idea on how I can check if a click is made, everywhere in my page except in one place.

So really, what I need, is a way to capture every single click I make, except in one particular DIV in my program.

If this can help you, the boxes that are not recognized by the click are contained in a table and in a tbody. Does this information make it easier to fix?

Comment: You should try to rephrase your issue, and maybe post your code, because honestly I cannot understand your problem. Do you want or not that the clicks inside your dynamic element get counted?

Comment: Yes, I want my click to be counted everywhere on my pages, including in my dynamic table element, everywhere except in one place. To make you in context. I click in one place that makes a certain counter increment and I want my counter to be reseted every time I click outside that div!

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of event listeners on Javascript?

Comment: Do you have other click handlers on your dynamic table element that might be preventing the event from bubbling to #html?  Post codez.

Comment: Not really. If you think it would be easier to accomplish my will, can you explained me how it would work :) !

Comment: Did one of the answers below help? Then be so kind and accept one of them. Else you should give some more information, so that we better understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should work for clicks on the whole page.

What you need is a similar click handler which listens on your area. This click handler should `return false` to prevent the first one to work as well. To bind this click handler even to new, dynamically created DOM elements, use `on()` with a css selector and create the new elements with a class (e.g. `special`)

```
 $(document)
  .on("click", ".special", function () {
    alert("Click on special div");
    return false;
  })
  .on("click", function () {
    alert("Click elsewhere");
  });
```

See my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/efckqng0/1

Comment: What if there are lots of `divs` in the page?

Comment: This won't work. The code I wrote is currently not working for me since my pages contains Dynamic element. I found the .live method, but still not luck. it's not catching my click !

Comment: @titi23 Then you should use a css class. I'll make that more obvious in my answer.

Comment: @FrancisForget I'll change my answer to use a css selector for the click handler which works even after adding such dynamic elements

Answer (score 1):

Give it a class, and check it accordingly, capturing only clicks that don't match that class:

```
$('html').click(function(e) {   
  if( !$(e.target).hasClass("thisClass") )
 {
  alert("you clicked outside the red!");
 }
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0nvgdm1j/1/

Comment: Your answer won't work. The code $("html").click does not recognize my click on the dynamic elements. The thing is, I need to have all my element working!

Comment: Sorry, I just read your last paragraph ("what I need, is a way to capture every single click I make, except in one particular DIV in my program")...